# Update badge value when user can change order of tab bar items

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

In my app I use this code to update notify counter:

```
[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items]
      objectAtIndex:3] setBadgeValue:unreadMsg];
```

Since the user can change the order of tabs (from "Other" menu managed from iOS), how can I find the new index to use for `objectAtIndex`?

[UPDATE]:
 - The Green Circle: is my TabBar Controller
 - The Red Circle: is the tab bar item that I want update
 - The Blue circle is where I want to check and update the badge value...

Anna I hope that is a little bit clear now.... And Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is index 3 the current view controller?  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820421/update-uitabbaritem-badgevalue-with-more-view

Comment: Loop through the tabBar.items array until you find the instance of the view controller class you are interested in then set that item's badgeValue.

Comment: Actually, you'll have to loop through the tabBarController.viewControllers array.  Something like that.

Comment: Working. I have tagged my tab bar item from xCode with 999 and i used this code:
        for (UIViewController *vc in self.tabBarController.viewControllers) {
            if (vc.tabBarItem.tag == 999) {
                vc.tabBarItem.badgeValue = unread;
            }
        }

Thanks so much Anna if you were here I'd pay a drink! :D